# Hangfire Console App using Memory and MySQL

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, console, hangfire

I have a console app with dependency injection and a dynamic recurring job. It uses a MySQL repository as the initial setup then saves it to the memory. Every time the job is triggered it checks if the schedule has been updated on the database thus updating the memory as well.

Here is the database model and database context:

```
public class Schedule
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Cron { get; set; }
    public string Task { get; set; }
}

public class HangfireServiceContext : DbContext
{
    public HangfireServiceContext(DbContextOptions<HangfireServiceContext> options) :base(options) 
    { 

    }

    public DbSet<Schedule> Schedules { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the Program class:

```
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = CreateHostBuilder().Build();
        var serviceProvider = host.Services;
        serviceProvider.GetService<IScheduler>().Execute();
    }


    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder()
    {
        return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
            {
                config.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                    .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            })
            .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
            {
                var connectionString = context.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default");
                services.AddDbContext<HangfireServiceContext>(options =>
                {
                    options.UseMySql(connectionString);
                });
                services.AddHangfire(x => x.UseMemoryStorage());
                services.AddHangfireServer();
                services.AddTransient<IScheduler, Scheduler>();
            });
    }
}
```

Here is the executed class:

```
public class Scheduler : IScheduler
{
    private List<Schedule> _schedules;
    private readonly HangfireServiceContext _context;

    public Scheduler(HangfireServiceContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        Initialize();
    }

    private void Initialize()
    {
        _schedules = _context.Schedules.ToList();
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
            .SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Version_170)
            .UseColouredConsoleLogProvider()
            .UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
            .UseRecommendedSerializerSettings()
            .UseMemoryStorage();

        foreach (var schedule in _schedules)
        {
            RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate($"job-id-{schedule.Id}", () => PrintCurrentTime(schedule.Id), schedule.Cron);
        }

        using (var server = new BackgroundJobServer())
        {
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }

    public void PrintCurrentTime(int scheduleId)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Schedule {scheduleId}: {DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay}");

        var dbSchedule = _context.Schedules.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == scheduleId);
        var existingSchedule = _schedules.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == scheduleId);

        if (dbSchedule.Task != existingSchedule.Task || dbSchedule.Name != existingSchedule.Name)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

There is no particular line on where the error happened but I am assuming that it is because it fails to get the dependency injected context from the class. Here is the complete error every recursion:

```
2022-12-19 09:52:09 [WARN]  (Hangfire.AutomaticRetryAttribute) Failed to process the job 'ea5c50a5-7615-4e45-9cbc-69dfbc866d92': an exception occurred. Retry attempt 1 of 10 will be performed in 00:00:33.
System.MissingMethodException
No parameterless constructor defined for this object.
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean wrapExceptions, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean wrapExceptions, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at Hangfire.JobActivator.SimpleJobActivatorScope.Resolve(Type type)
   at Hangfire.Server.CoreBackgroundJobPerformer.Perform(PerformContext context)
   at Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<PerformJobWithFilters>b__0()
   at Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.InvokePerformFilter(IServerFilter filter, PerformingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.PerformJobWithFilters(PerformContext context, IEnumerable`1 filters)
   at Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.Perform(PerformContext context)
   at Hangfire.Server.Worker.PerformJob(BackgroundProcessContext context, IStorageConnection connection, String jobId)
```

Comment: which line has error?

Comment: @viveknuna I have updated the the question to include the error.